# how to terminate a javafx.concurrent.Service in javafx 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, java.util.concurrent

Hi this is the structure of my application.
MCVE:

```
 @FXML
void OnSimulateClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if (event.getSource() == simulatebutton) {
        primaryStage = (Stage) simulatebutton.getScene().getWindow();
        pane = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(TDC.class.getResource("view/Simulation.fxml"));
        scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

FXML

```
<Pane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="750.0"   xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mdw.tdc.view.SimulationController" >
<children>
  <Button fx:id="abortbutton" layoutX="650.0" layoutY="230.0"  onAction="#onAbortClicked"  text="Abort" />
  <Button fx:id="homebutton" layoutX="650.0" layoutY="330.0"onAction="#onHomeClicked" text="Home"  />
  <TextArea fx:id="logscreen" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="395.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
</children>
</Pane>
```

controller

```
public class SimulationController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private Button homebutton;
@FXML
private TextArea logscreen;
@FXML
private Button abortbutton;
private Simulate simulate;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        simulate = new Simulate(list, logscreen);
        simulate.setOnCancelled(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Simulation Aborted by User...");
            }
        });
        simulate.setOnFailed(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Simulation Failed...");
            }
        });
        simulate.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Simulation Success...");
            }
        });
        simulate.start();
}


@FXML
void onAbortClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException,
InterruptedException {
    if (event.getSource() == abortbutton) {
        simulate.cancel();
    }
}
}

@FXML
void onHomeClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if (event.getSource() == homebutton) {
        simulate.reset();
        /*back to Home screen*/
    pane = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(TDC.class.getResource("view/Simulation.fxml"));
    scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Simulate Sercice

```
public class Simulate extends Service<Void> {
private ObservableList<TestData> list;
private TextArea logscreen;
private ConsoleStream consoleStream;

public Simulate(ObservableList<TestData> list, TextArea logscreen) {
    this.list = list;
    this.logscreen = logscreen;
}

@Override
protected Task<Void> createTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            consoleStream = new ConsoleStream(logscreen);
            consoleStream.start();
            /*Some Code*/
            System.out.println("End of  Simulation");
            return null;
        }
    };
}

/* Few other methods called from inside my code inside createTask()>call() method */

// using this method to flag when cancelled
public void isFlagged(boolean b) {
    consoleStream.isFlagged(true);
    consoleStream.setOnCancelled(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
            consoleStream.reset();
        }
    });
    consoleStream.cancel();

}
}
```

ConsoleStream Service

```
public class ConsoleStream extends Service<Void> {
private PipedOutputStream outPipedOutputStream, errorPipedOutputStream;
private PipedInputStream outPipedInputStream, errorPipedInputStream;
private TextArea logscreen;
private Console outCon;

public ConsoleStream(TextArea logscreen) {
    this.logscreen = logscreen;
}

@Override
protected Task<Void> createTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            try {

                System.err.flush();
                System.out.flush();

                outPipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
                outPipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(
                        outPipedInputStream);

                System.setOut(new PrintStream(outPipedOutputStream));

                errorPipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
                errorPipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(
                        errorPipedInputStream);

                System.setErr(new PrintStream(errorPipedOutputStream));

                outCon = new Console(outPipedInputStream, logscreen);
                outCon.setOnCancelled(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("ConsoleStream Aborted by User...");
                        outCon.reset();
                    }
                });
                outCon.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}

public void isFlagged(boolean b) {
    outCon.cancel();
}
}
```

Console Service

```
public class Console extends Service<Void> {

private final InputStream inputStream;
private TextArea logscreen;

public Console(PipedInputStream errorPipedInputStream, TextArea logscreen) {
    inputStream = errorPipedInputStream;
    this.logscreen = logscreen;
}

@Override
protected Task<Void> createTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            while(isCancelled()){
                inputStream.close();
                break;
            }               
            try {
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                while (br.readLine() != null) {
                    String read = br.readLine();
                    logscreen.appendText(read + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}

}
```

This is the first attempt at JavaFx not sure this is good way of doing. any suggestions are appriciated
Thanks

Comment: How do you check that it never got cancelled?

Comment: i believe cancelled method is called as soon as service.cancel() is encountered

Comment: This is not the correct way to check it because the `if()` will only check once whether the service was cancelled or not, when you just start your service. You need to add a listener to the `setOnCancelled()` property of the Service. For ex : `service.setOnCancelled(event -> System.out.println("Cancelled"));`

Comment: ya i am using that have skinned out that part for posting

Comment: simulate.setOnCancelled(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
     System.out.println("Aborted by user...");
     
         
    }
   });

Comment: Any this never gets called? You should most probably remove the unwanted code and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90911/discussion-between-uday-and-itachiuchiha).